# Can't access token using Alfresco OAuth

Tags: oauth-2.0, alfresco, alfresco-share

I cloned this [repo](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-oauth-sample) in order to test the sample application I created on the Alfresco Cloud. I am following all the steps provided by the sample as follows:

1. Request an Authorization code
2. The app returns authorization code
3. This code is extended for an Access token
4. Final step is to call a URL using the access token

**Issue**

When I try to use this access token the app prompts me to login, I use the correct login details (Alfresco Cloud) and I get the following reponse:

```
{
  "error":"invalid_request",
  "error_description":"Duplicate access token"
}
```

My approach to fix this was to create a new app but I am still getting the same error. Has anybody experienced this problem before. I can't find anything related to this and plus Alfresco documentation is not very clear at least for my level of knowledge.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You should only ever use one of: OAuth details, Alfresco Token, Username + Password. It sounds like you're sending more than one, hence the error